# onclick Modal box in single product page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to create a onclick modal in single product page. I have put together the following:

**FILES**
`js/modal-jquery.js` and `modal-box.html` are uploaded in **child theme**'s directory.
`css` is in child theme's css.

I enqueued the jquery in **functions.php**

```
// Enqueue MODAL Jquery JS 
function my_enqueue_stuff() {
    if(is_singular( 'product' ))
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'modal-jquery-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modal-jquery.js');
// wp_enqueue_script( 'modal-box', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'modal-box.html');
    }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_stuff' );
```

LINK in **functions.php**

```
// POPUP LINK
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'popup-modal', 3 );
    function popup-modal() { 
        // $file = file directory to modal-box.html
        echo '<a class="js-open-modal" href="#" data-modal-id="popup"> Click me </a>';
    }
```

**modal-box.html**

```
<div id="popup" class="modal-box">  
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>Modal Title</h3>
  </header>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Modal Body</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="#" class="js-modal-close">Close Button</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

I've been trying to add modal-box.html into `function popup-modal()`.
I've also tried to enqueue `modal-box.html` but it gives an error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

How can I load the html file as an external file into the single product page? If this is not the right way to do it, how can I add a modal box to the single product page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `is_singular( 'product' )` use woocommerce's own `is_product()`

For the modal, what about including it in the footer, also only on product pages, like this?:

```
function your_modal_footer(){
  if( !is_product() ){
     return;
  }
?>
<div id="popup" class="modal-box">  
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>Modal Title</h3>
  </header>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Modal Body</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="#" class="js-modal-close">Close Button</a>
  </footer>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_modal_footer');
```

I would add a `style="display:none;"` to the popup div and then make it visible onclick of the popup's trigger.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why does it work only in the footer? I've tried with header and body but none of them work.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that this same thing doesn't work when added in header or footer, because it is actually exactly the same in that sense - in all cases you are simply injecting a bit of html on the page. All locations work, footer is usually used for modals to prevent the delay of loading an element earlier on the page that won't be seen at least until it finished loading.

Comment: @PlainH2O you could also use the same exact function only replacing the wp_footer action hook with wp_head to have the modal injected in the header https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/

You could use hooks specific to the theme or plugins you are using to inject it in the body. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Thanks! Then most likely is the theme i am using. I was wondering why I have this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` when I tried it with body and header, but it works in footer. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You're very welcome @PlainH2O :) I am now thinking that your issue must have been the function name popup-modal . PHP does not support dashes in function names, I think. It should be popup_modal

Comment: Also you need to include your file properly to have the html in a separate file that you are adding.

Comment: Thanks so much Tami! I'm new to Wordpress and PHP, thanks for sharing and I learned something new again!

Comment: @PlainH2O WordPress and PHP is what I specialize in, don't hesitate to reach out if you need help again :) Also, when in doubt the official WP documentation is usually a great resource.

Comment: Thnaks Tami! Is it possible to make the page stays in placed when the close button is clicked? I posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893328/stays-in-position-when-modal-box-is-closed

Comment: Practically everything is possible in web dev :) Will check it out