# Stays in position when modal box is closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a popup modal box. When the close button is clicked, the page scrolls back to the top of the window. How can I have the page stays in its position after the close button is clicked?

Here is the **jquery** I use for the modal box. The full demo can be found here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html

```
$(function(){

var appendthis =  ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");

  $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    //$(".js-modalbox").fadeIn(500);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#'+modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());
  });  
  
  
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
  $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(".modal-overlay").remove();
  });
});
 
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".modal-box").css({
    top: ($(window).height() - $(".modal-box").outerHeight()) / 2,
    left: ($(window).width() - $(".modal-box").outerWidth()) / 2
  });
});
 
$(window).resize();
 
});
```

Here is the **html** I use for the modal box.

```
<div id="popup" class="modal-box" style="display:none;">  
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>Modal Title</h3>
  </header>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Modal Body</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="#" class="js-modal-close">Close Button</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: do you have a link where this can be checked "live"?

Comment: This is the one I'm using https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant if you could share a link to the site where you are working, with this code running?

Comment: Thanks @Tami! After some struggling, managed to make it works. I added this `$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();` and it works. Really appreciate your kindness and patience for willing to help.

Comment: Glad you got it working! :D